# Transform datetime from string to date

Tags: r, datetime

I have a string of datetime like this:

```
"Wed Jan 01 01:37:41 CST 2014"
```

How can I transfrom it into date in R.

I tried

```
 strptime(t, "%a %b %d %X", tz="CST")
```

The field of year is hard for me.

Comment: What problem are you having? Your `strptime` works for me. You could also do `strptime(t, "%a %b %d %X CST %Y", tz="CST")` if you want to explicitly grab the year

Comment: Thank you, this works. I tried many times on that "CST".

Comment: Please feel free to post the answer and accept it to show that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Jake Burkhead

```
strptime(t, "%a %b %d %X CST %Y", tz="CST")
```